# jQuery fadeIn Doesn't seem to run?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Very Simple jQuery Project as a Practice. I have set up a Button ( #btn ) and I wanted to see if it was possible to fade in a Div when i click the button. I set up a Fiddle, is anything wrong with code itself?

Link to [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0167bmd/).

--Code--

-jQuery-

```
> jQuery(function() { 
>           $('#btn').click(function(){
>               $('#text2').fadeIn(1000);
>               });      })
```

--HTML--

```
<div id="btn">

    <button>Click Me!</button>


</div>

<div id="text">

<h1> hello </h1>

</div>

<div id="text2">

<h2 style> Hi There! <h2>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fadeIn()` works with `display:none;` css property, not with opacity.
You could use `.css('opacity', '1')` or animate something for that...

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m0167bmd/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you also forgot to download the Jquery.min.js on JS fiddle

here is the link

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="btn">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
</div>

<div id="text">
<h1> hello </h1>
</div>

<div id="text2">
<h2> Hi There! </h2>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
               $('#text2').fadeIn(1000);
        });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#text2 {display:none;}
```

(`FadeIn()` works with `display:none` not with the `opacity`)

Answer (score 0):

Put the ID 'btn' on the button, not on the surrounding div.
Then it should work.

```
<button id="btn'">Click me</button>
```

Comment: You can add a click event on every element, not just on a button. The problem is that he is trying to use fadeIn() with the opacity css property not with display none...

Comment: You're totally right. Overseen the opacity thing at his CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JQuery like below:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/m0167bmd/2/)

```
$(function() { 
    $('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#text2').css('opacity', '1').fadeIn(1000)
  });
});
```

Because you have the opacity set to 0, the content will not appear. I've used the `css` method to set the opacity to one before the call to `fadeIn`

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0167bmd/13/)

check out

```
$(function() { 
    $('#btn button').click(function(){
    $('#text2').css('opacity', '1')
  });
});
```

css

```
#text2 { 

    opacity: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help to you.please remember, you can `show`, `fadeIn`,`slideDown` any element,after you set it's style property `display:none`. If you do not want to set the `display:none` property as style then use `fadeToggle` it works fine.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- html with internal style-->
    <button class="clickme">show Honey</button>
    <div class="mydiv" style="display:none;">
      <h2>This is the content what I want to show.</h2>
    </div>

    <!-- js--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".clickme").click(function(){
          $(".mydiv").fadeIn(1000);
          //you can use slideDown,show,fadeToggle(fadeIn once click, fadeOut when you click again.)
        });
     });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```